# Combined search: 'choice filter' for metadata + 'search box' for document content?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I can work with the 'choice filter' (as a drop-down menu and in a created 'Web Part Page' within a given site) for selecting files in the 'Document Library'.

The 'choice filter' can be connected to the 'Document Library' and I am able to select documents within the library based on specific tags.

This selection is done via metadata columns in the 'Document Library'.
This feature has been implemented and works fine (i.e. selection of files based on metadata columns in the 'Document Library').

However, I'll need to narrow-down the choice further by searching for specific keywords present within the documents in 'Document Library'.

Currently, I can search within documents for specific keywords (via a search Centre/Box) or via the filter choice mentioned above but the requirement is for the two to be combined.

Any idea on this?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/fast-query-language-fql-syntax-reference

Comment: Clarification: The 'choice filter' drop-down menu (Web Part) needs to be the primary source for metada. After this, a 'Refined Search' (as a Web Part as well) should be implemented (in the same page as the 'choice filter' drop-down menu Web Part) for content search with documents. Results of the two combined Web Part searches should be shown on the same page as well.

Comment: it might be better if you add example in your questions e.g. Values of the dropdown:  'Active, Pending, Close' then Title of the document.  So show document only if it is Active and Title = "my special document" is it correct?

Comment: Example:                                                                                              Values of the  'choice filter' drop-down menu (Web Part): 'Active, Pending, Close'. IF 'Active' is CHOSEN, THEN type 'this specific keyword' (that can be present WITHIN any document in the library) SO THAT 'Active' documents with 'this specific keyword' are retrieved. The title of the document is of no interest, while some specific keywords within the documents are.

Comment: I have just found out the SOLUTION: go the document web part ('Categories', 'Apps', 'Documents'). Then 'Edit Web Part', 'Advanced' and thick the 'Display search box'. Now the search can be performed on content (from metadata).